# Draw line after every click event - Google Maps click event only fires once

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I want to allow the user to click on the map

- the last click event will be used to set the X and Y coordinates for **point B**
- **point A** has predefined coordinates 2.42249, 3.82618.

**EDIT:**

- The previous lines should be cleared - and not visible on the map.

Find the code bellow, the issue with my code is that the click-event only fires once. I want to draw the line after every click.

```
function initialize() 
{
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.42249, 3.82618),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event)
    {
        drawLine(event.latLng);
    });
}

function drawLine(loc)
{

    mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.42249, 3.82618),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    flightPlanCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(2.42249, 3.82618),
        new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat(), loc.lng())
    ];
    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Why are you initialising the map every time you add a line? That can't be good.

Comment: I'm not familiar - but I think I have to initialize my map on every click because I want to get rid of the previous lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy points out the problem, you're recreating the map each time you click it.  Try making your `map` variable global so it's available to both functions, and get rid of the duplicate code between both functions.  Something like:

```
var map, flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline();

function initialize() 
{
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.42249, 3.82618),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event)
    {
        drawLine(event.latLng);
    });
}

function drawLine(loc) {
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(2.42249, 3.82618),
        loc
    ];

    flightPath.setMap(null);

    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

(updated to demonstrate clearing the polyline off the map each time you click)

Comment: oh really?  New requirement, you didn't mention it in your original question.  Make the `flightPath` variable global too.  In the `drawLine` function set its map to null to remove it using `flightPath.setMap(null)`, so you always draw a new one.  Alternatively draw it once and drawLine simply updates its coordinates if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. 
Create the map only once.
Create the poligon only once.
Then just keep adding lines

```
var map;
var flightPath;
var firstLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(2.42249, 3.82618);

function initialize()
{
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.42249, 3.82618),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event)
    {
        drawLine(event.latLng);
    });
}

function createLine(loc){

    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}

function drawLine(loc)
{
    if (flightPath == null)
        createLine();

    flightPlanCoordinates = [
        firstLatLng,
        loc
    ];
    flightPath.setPath(flightPlanCoordinates);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: This has strange behaviour, point B does change and doesn't have constant x and y coordinates.

Comment: Try it now. The strange behaviour is because the way the Polyline is created. The right way is to create the path array after the first click, then wait the other click.

Comment: Your code takes the previous click coordinates as point A and the new click coordinates for point B. Point A should always have its predefined coordinates 2.42249, 3.82618

Comment: So set ur unchanged latlng as "const" LatLng instance. And set the path. The polyline object don't need to recreated, but if u want to you can, just remember to destroy the old object.